# Signatures real use case?

Tags: signature

I'm new to this Ethereum community and I've been reading about signatures processes in Ethereum and smart contracts processes and always end up finding a general use-case where someone signs a "hello world" message with a private key and someone can verify who did it using its public key. However, I'm having trouble finding a proper real case scenario for this signatures process. Is there anyone who can enlighten me and show me a real use case where I can make use of these signatures?

Comment: So how exactly does the title of this question represent anything of what is actually being asked in it???

Comment: Thought the same, so I suggested an edit

Comment: I apologize, I approved the edit. I was reading other threads and mistitled apparently

Comment: "real case scenario for this signatures process"? To the best of my knowledge, every transaction made on the Ethereum block-chain such a real case scenario.

Comment: The question as stated is too open and unrelated to ethereum. Signatures are used in many cases, like voting, identity verification, pseudo random number generation.

Comment: I think possibly the question is "What are signatures, what do they prove and how do they work?"